# DependencyProperty string, onChange while typing

Tags: c#, xaml, search

I want to create a simple searchbox, so I have a textbox and when someone types a searchterm I want to execute the search method.

The problem is that the onChange method executes when I change click out of the textbox and I want the onChange event executed while I am typing.

```
<TextBox Text="{Binding SearchTerm}" />

public static readonly DependencyProperty SearchTermProperty =
            DependencyProperty.Register("SearchTerm", typeof(string), typeof(MainWindow), new PropertyMetadata(string.Empty, OnCaptionPropertyChanged));
        private static void OnCaptionPropertyChanged(DependencyObject dependencyObject, 
               DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e) 
        {
            ((MainWindow)dependencyObject).SearchTracks(e.NewValue.ToString());
        }
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
<TextBox Text="{Binding SearchTerm, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" />
```

Answer (score 2):

You must change the [UpdateSourceTrigger](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.binding.updatesourcetrigger.aspx) attribute to ProperyChanged.

```
<TextBox Text="{Binding SearchTerm,UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" />
```

If you also want to **track special keys**, you have to register to the [PreviewKeyDown](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.previewkeydown.aspx)-Event.

Answer (score 0):

Try using PreviewTextInput instead.